# Return a queryset of all jobs that a logged in user applied for

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am building a job portal where users can apply for any job listed on the system. Assuming a user is logged in, and has applied for different job positions, I want to be able to return all the jobs he has applied for and pass it to my template. I have two models: Job and Applicants

Models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(choices=country_state, max_length=20)
    description = RichTextUploadingField()
    requirement = RichTextUploadingField()
    years_of_experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(choices=JOB_TYPE, max_length=10)
    last_date = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    filled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Applicants(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applicants')
    experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    degree = models.CharField(choices=DEGREE_TYPE, blank=True, max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.get_full_name()} Applied'
```

In my views.py I tried getting the logged in user with request.user and filter the Applicants model with the request.user. Then I filtered jobs in the applicant job list.

Views.py

```
class AppliedJobs(ListView):
    model = Applicants
    template_name = 'my_job_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'jobs'
    ordering = ['-date']

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('login')))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(self.request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        my_job_list = Applicants.objects.filter(user=user).values_list('job', flat=True)
        return Applicants.objects.filter(job__in=my_job_list)
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do this. It returns jobs but not quite the way it should. I need it to list out only jobs the user applied for.

template.html

```
      {% for job in jobs %}
                 <ul class="job-listings mb-5">
                  <li class="job-listing d-block d-sm-flex pb-3 pb-sm-0 align-items-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'job-detail' job.id %}"></a>
                    <div class="job-listing-logo">
                        <img src="{{ job.user.profile.image.url }}" alt="Free Website Template by Free-Template.co" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>

                    <div class="job-listing-about d-sm-flex custom-width w-100 justify-content-between mx-4">
                      <div class="job-listing-position custom-width w-50 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        <h4>{{ job.title }}</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="job-listing-location mb-3 mb-sm-0 custom-width w-25">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt"></i>{{ job.location }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="job-listing-meta">
                          {% if job.type == 'Full time' %}
                            <span class="badge featured-badge badge-success">Full time</span>
                                 {% elif job.type == 'Part time' %}
                            <span class="badge featured-badge badge-primary">Part time</span>
                              {% elif job.type == 'Internship' %}
                            <span class="badge featured-badge badge-warning">Internship</span>
                              {% else %}
                            <span style="color: #ffffff;" class="badge featured-badge badge-warning">Contract</span>
                          {% endif %}
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </li>
                </ul>
       {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`my_job_list` is already the correct list of `Applicants` objects for your user. By adding `values_list('job')` at the end, you're just creating a list of job ids, and your final line that filters by these values actually adds all applications by other users for the same jobs, which is not what you want.

So you just need to do:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Applicants.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).distinct('job').select_related('job')
```

I've added `select_related` in order to fetch the associated `Job` rows in the same query, and, for PostgreSQL only, `distinct` to make sure only one application is fetched for each job (in case a user applies multiple times for the same job)

In your template, you can then loop through the applications:

```
{% for application in applications %}
   {{ application.job.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

You could also just fetch the list of jobs by querying `Job` directly, but that means you won't have the application details in your template:

```
Job.objects.filter(applicants__user=user).distinct()
```

Comment: I get a "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" error, when i do this. I am using django sqlite3 db

Comment: distinct('job') only works on PostgreSQL. If you don't use postgres, just remove the distinct clause.

Comment: now I am getting a Reverse for 'job-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found

Comment: Means that somewhere you are passing an empty object to your {% url %} template tag.

Comment: oh yeah, I am passing a link to the detail view of the job  '<a href="{% url 'job-detail' job.id %}"></a>'. if I remove that, then it works. But I want the user to link back to the detail view of the job from this page.

Comment: If you loop through applications, then `job` is not defined. Might need to do `application.job.id`.

Comment: `<a href="{% url 'job-detail' application.id %}"></a>`. Thank you

Comment: That's probably not the correct id, if `application` is an `Application` and your `job-detail` url is expecting a Job id.

Comment: It is. my context object name is applications like you wrote above so `application in applications`. `application.id` gets the job/application id so it worked

Comment: But job id and application id are not the same. It works if by chance your application with id = 1 is for job with id = 1. But if the page expects a job id, it should be `application.job.id`.